# What is the difference between string.c_str() and &string[0]?

Tags: c++, c

What are the differences between `string.c_str()` and `&string[0]`?

Regarding performance my guess is that `&string[0]` is a little faster than string.c_str() as it doesn't require a function call.

Regarding safety and stability common sense tells me that `string.c_str()` should have some checks implemented, but I don't know, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: One invokes undefined behaviour and the other doesn't.

Comment: `string::operator[]` certainly IS a function call. It uses syntactical sugar to look like array access, but it is a function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++98 there is no guarantee that the internal array is null terminated; in other words `string.data()[string.size()]` results in undefined behavior. The implementation will then reallocate the array with the null termination when `c_str()` is called but can leave the null terminator off when it isn't.

This also means that `&string[0]` is not guaranteed to be null terminated (it is essentially a detour to `data()`)

In C++11 the null termination guarantee is specified so `string.data()==string.c_str()` is always valid.

Comment: so in **C++98** `&string[0]` could be <> `string.c_str()` and result in undefined behavior when `string.size() = 0` and in **C++11** `&string[0] == string.c_str()` always ?

Comment: I didn't understand this part: "_The implementation will then reallocate the array with the null termination when c_str() is called but can leave the null terminator off when it isn't._"

Comment: @clickstefan the C++98 standard allows strings to share the internal array and have other strings point to a substring (which can't be null terminated), when that substring needs the `c_str()´ it will need to allocate it's own copy and add the terminator. and since it just allocated the array it will then be able to use that as its internal array.